# How to change the plot starting point?

Tags: plotting

I tried to translate this Python plot to Mathematica:

Python:

[image: python plot]

Mathematica:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

The Mathematica code works fine except that the plot starts from 0 on X-axis. How to let it start from 1?

Comment: Take a look at `AxesOrigin`.

Comment: @Kuba I added `AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}`, it works. Thank you for telling me the `AxesOrigin`, I though it should be something start with `axis...`.

Comment: DataRange would also work. Or you could add an x-value to each  y-value.

Comment: You can use `ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], Filling -> Axis, DataRange -> {0, 9}]` to get a plot more similar to the Python one.

Comment: @Karsten7 @Sjoerd C. de Vries Thank you. `DataRange` looks better. There's really a lot to learn in Mathematica.

Comment: Related: [(1555)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1555/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes! Thanks.