# Adding +2015 to each value of my x-axis

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I want to change all of the values of my x-axis by +2015

The problem is, I evaluated a large expression using incremental values {i,1,85} and plotted that data.  The Plot's x-axis is 1 to 85, as expected.  But I want to change it to 2015 to 2100 as these are the years that are represented in my calculation.

Is there a way I can just scale my axis by adding 2015 without messing with my expressions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If your data is stored in a list of ordered pairs called `lst`, then just do `{2015, 0} + # & /@ lst` or `Table[{2015, 0} + lst[[k]], {k, Length@lst}]`.

Comment: If you added some sample data/code, answering would involve less guess-work. You can either alter your data or your [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html).

Comment: Maybe `ListPlot[#, 
     Ticks -> {(Transpose@{#[[All, 1]], 2015 + #[[All, 1]]})[[;; ;; 
            10]] &@#, Automatic}] &@Transpose@{#, #} &@Range[0, 85]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change step size of ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/how-to-change-step-size-of-listplot)

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate, but it'll take me less time to repeat than find the duplicate question. ([Found it](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1555/7167).)  If you have a list of single values (as opposed to x,y pairs), perhaps the easiest approach is to use the `DataRange` option to ListPlot

```
data = Table[Sin[i/10], {i, 1, 85}];
ListPlot[data, DataRange -> {2015, 2100}]
```

[image]